# Ubuntu mate 16.04 matlab installation permission denied

Tags: 16.04, mate, matlab

[image]

Please refer the image above.

I am not able to proceed with the installation of `Matlab` on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 x64.

Please help me to proceed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the instructions as per this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)

You have to perform `sudo ./install`

The above problem is due to need in administrator rights to install the software. `sudo` command would provide you the administrator rights to proceed with the installation.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.